# rMarkdown trouble loading csv in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create an R markdown using the csv NFL_DATA.csv. However when I try to use `knitr` I get the error:

> Error in nrow(NFL_DATA): object 'NFL_DATA' not found Calls:
>   ... in_dir -> inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   nrow Execution halted

Here is the beginning of my code:

````
title: "XXXXXX"
author: "XXXXXX"
date: "December 11, 2017"
output: html_document
font-family: "Arial"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

---

## Introduction

XXXXXXXXXXXXX.

---

## Data

 We used the site data.world.com to find my data. The dataset can be retrieved at [NFL_DATA.csv](https://data.world/alice-c/nfl-fines-and-suspensions/workspace/file?filename=All+Penalties.csv).

There are `r nrow(NFL_DATA)` observations in the NFL data set and `r length(NFL_DATA)` variables. The variables are:

```{r echo=FALSE, comment=""}
names(NFL_DATA)
```
````

When I run it the `knitr` does not work and gives an error message. However when I just run the last piece of code for `names(NFL_DATA)` it does work and it displays all the variable names. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have to call your data set `NFL_DATA` explicitly in the RMD file. It's not enough when rendering the file that `NFL_DATA` is in your environment.

Comment: To add to @J_F, RMarkdown will start with a clean environment so all variables defined in your R session will not be available when running your RMarkdown code through `knitr`.

Comment: I saved my file as NFL_DATA.RData... So if i add this code to the mardown should it work?: load(file="NFL_DATA.RData")

Answer (score 0):

Try this after editing the code to point to wherever you stored the csv file locally.

````
---
title: "NFL Fines and Suspensions Analysis"
author: "anAuthor"
date: "12/8/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Read Data

Here is example code to read the nfl data


```{r readData,echo=FALSE}
nfldata <- read.csv("./data/All Penalties.csv",header=TRUE)
```

There are `r nrow(nfldata)` observations in the NFL data set and `r length(nfldata)` variables. The variables are:

```{r}
names(nfldata) 
```
````